# Scribble uses too much memory?

Tags: memory, memory-management, racket, scribble

"scribble" is the racket documentation tool. I have got a problem with the following example. When N=30, scribble uses ~500M memory. It seems very difficult to have more than 300 such examples in a single scribble document.

```
cat <<EOF
#lang scribble/manual
@(require scribble/eval)

@title["hello world"]   
EOF
N=30
for((i=0;i<N;i++));do
    cat <<EOF
@(examples
       (require racket/snip)
         (require racket/class)
       (make-object image-snip% "a.jpg"))

EOF
done
) > x.scrbl
scribble x.scrbl
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `examples` creates a new evaluator each time, which is rather expensive. If possible, create a single evaluator for your entire document:

```
#lang scribble/manual
@(require scribble/eval)
@(define the-eval (make-base-eval))

@examples[#:eval the-eval
(require racket/snip)
(require racket/class)
(make-object image-snip% "a.jpg")
]
...
@examples[#:eval the-eval
<more stuff>
]
```

That should use significantly less memory.

Comment: `(cat <<EOF
    #lang scribble/manual
    @(require scribble/eval)
    @(define e (make-base-eval))
    @title["hello world"]   
    @(interaction-eval #:eval e
           (begin
           (require racket/snip)
           (require racket/class)))
    EOF
    
    N=1000
    
    for((i=0;i<N;i++));do
        cat <<EOF
    @(examples #:eval e
           (make-object image-snip% "a.jpg"))
    EOF
    done
    ) > x.scrbl` I change it like this. When N=1000, only 200M memory is used. The problem is solved. Thank you!!!

Comment: yes. I follow your answer. Only 200M memory is used when N=1000.